# Destop application using arcobjects library

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, java

I develop a destop application with following environment -

1) Java jdk version 6 update 25 (for 32bit ).

2) Java Arcobjects Library.

3) Window Xp.

Its working smoothly on 32 bit Computer , my problem is i need to provide this application to a team member who works on .net with following configration -

1)Java jdk version 6 update 25 ( for 64 bit ).

2) .Net Arcobjects Library.

3) Window 7.

What are the things i need to do to make my application work on that computer.

Comment: Are both development env. using ArcGIS 10.0?

Comment: Ya , both have ArcGis 10 environment

Comment: What app (e.g. visual studio) did you use to compile your app?

Comment: I used eclipse(juno) and wxported a executable jar from it.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you simply compile the application into a jar file give it to your team member to run. I admit this response is too simplistic but it appears your problem is that simple to me. Let me know if there is something I need to know in order to help further.

Comment: I did what u say initialy , but there seems to be problem , my team mate is having arcGis desktop license environment and i build my tool in engine environment . I changed my tool variable to be compatible with arcGis desktop licence environment , but i am still having following error -- " Unable to initialize ArcObjects environment.
AutomationException: 0x800401f5 - The specified product or version does not exist on this machine. in 'ArcGISVersion.Version'"

Comment: Make sure the first line of the code in the main section of your class iniatializes the engine interop before you add any other line. You need to initialize the engine and enter the STA before any thing else is done with arcobject java sdk. For a console application you start with EngineInitializer.initializeEngine(); and a visual application EngineInitializer.initializeVisualBeans(); There are other issues as well that might be causing this problem; however try the above and we'll proceed from there.

Comment: Also have your mate install the arcgis engine runtime on his machine or at least use a machine that has ArcGIS installed. The compiled application needs the engine runtime in order to run on a separate machine. You can contact esri support for trial versions of the runtime.

Comment: You means to say that it wont work on just installing ArcGIS destop and Arc object SDK , else than that an engine runtime is required?

Comment: But what if i want to run it in ArcGis Destop environment , unlike Engine installation it does not provide any runtime instalation for window.

Comment: Hi Newbee sorry for taking too long in responding to you. So this is what you need to know. From ArcGIS 9.2 release and onwards releases, you do not need to have the Engine runtime installed on the machine if you already have any of the releases already installed (i.e ArcGIS 9.2 upwards). However if you don't have it on the target machine you would have to have the Engine runtime installed or simply install of the above mentioned releases of ArcGIS desktop and you should be good to go.

Comment: Dont worry about the runtime installation window, the default settings will be picked from the target machine if you followed the right constructs in your code for license verifications and the like. Also please be a bit clear on what you mean by "run it in ArcGis Destop environment"; are you trying to develop an ArcGIS extension or a stand-alone ArcObjects Desktop application?

Comment: By "run it in ArcGis Destop environment" i mean that target machine has installed ArcGis Destop on it and nothing else .

Comment: Yes it is a stand-alone ArcObjects Desktop application. Don't know how but its working now , i just install additional ArcGIS engine runtime over target Machine and its worrking , even though i have not authorise the engine licence over that system.

Answer (score 0):

Your team mate needs to install the java ArcObject library and setup the project properly with a Java compatible IDE, such as Eclipse or Netbeans. Here the .Net version of the ArcObjects has nothing to do because you are talking about a java project.

Comment: I dont want him to run application through IDE , i want that he can just double click and use the app , as i am using on my computer without use of IDE.